# Object as Type Returns Null - But Object IS of Type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, types, null

My program keeps throwing an error because it is getting to a line it should never get to.  I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012, and when I run my program, it of course halts the code and lets me debug it by hovering my cursor over variables to get all of their information.  In my code, I have a variable defined far earlier in the code that is known as curObj, along with a string known as part.  curObj's value is of type CustomObject.  However, the following if statement returns false, anyway:

```
object curObj = null;

foreach (Dictionary<string, CustomVariable> variables in vars)
{
    if (!variables.ContainsKey(part)) continue;
    curObj = GetValueOfVariable(variables[part]);
    break;
}

CustomObject cusObj = curObj as CustomObject;
if (cusObj != null)
    curObj = GetValueOfVariable(((CustomObject) curObj).GetVariable(part));
else
    curObj = curObj.GetType().GetField(part).GetValue(curObj);
```

For some reason, even though curObj IS, in fact, a CustomObject, as evidenced by the details given me by Visual Studio when it runs into this error, cusObj is still null when it gets to this point.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is curObj actually some sort of of proxy? I've had this issue with NHibernate and its lazy loaded proxies.

Comment: Can you show the line where you define `curObj`?

Comment: I suppose I can, yes.

Comment: You've showed where you assign `curObj`. Where do you define it? And what does `GetValueOfVariable` do?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I don't believe so, but I'm not exactly 100% sure as to how to define a proxy in C#

Comment: Use `var x = curObj.GetType()` before you try to use `as` and see what its full type is.

Comment: Probably variables.ContainsKey(part) returns false for all your "variables"

Comment: @JeroenVannevel GetValueOfVariable gets the value of a variable.  It is recursive in case a variable's value is another variable.  When I say variable right now, though, I mean the variable of my own custom scripting language that this piece of code is actually from.  The variables just hold an object as a value.

Comment: @HallvarHelleseth But curObj isn't null when the error is thrown...It is, in fact, an instance of my CustomObject.

Comment: Have you checked if `GetField(part)` returns no `null`?

Comment: No, I haven't, Konrad.  But that's not the problem - the problem is that my code should never be GETTING to that line as long as curObj is of type CustomObject, which it is when this error is getting thrown.

Comment: @bballer13snTV, where is `CustomObject` defined? In the same assembly?

Comment: One silly question: is it possible that you have a class named CustomObject in two namespaces? For example, generated entity (NHibernate or Entity Framework) is named CustomObject, and your model is also named CustomObject? Can you add a line before if saying string s = curObj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName? What I mean is that curObj is obviously NOT CustomObject - it only takes a different angle of viewing and you'll see what it actually is...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Alright, I just did a check, @sysexpand.  It is, in fact, the same type of CustomObject as it should be, and that "as CustomObject" is speaking about the same type of object.

Comment: @KonradKokosa Yes, same assembly.

Comment: Then that is the puzzle...

Comment: Puzzle indeed, @bballer13snTV, can you show us values of `cusObj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` and `curObj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` on the line when cast is done?